# How DNS works if I have application in app.domain.example and other principal page domain.example?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cpanel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I do that? I have the app in `app.domain.example` in ElasticBeanstalk in AWS and I have `domain.example` in a CPanel that shows the principal page with info, contact, etc.

How do I redirect both?

**UPDATE : 
The static page is in Shared Hosting and is not a dedicated IP, then, that was the problem, I have contacted with them and They tell me that it's not posible access to the static page by IP address (something like : 200.23.40.92/usernamehosting)**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Each record would point to a different IP address,  or A record.

`domain.example` zone file:

```
@ IN A 192.0.2.1. # apex domain eg domain.example
app IN A 203.0.113.2 # app.domain.example
```

In this example, `domain.exampl` points to one IP, and `app.domain.example` points to a different IP.

You can implement this approach in AWS Route 53, or any DNS service provider.

Comment: Yes thanks! but the static page is in Shared Hosting and is not a dedicated IP

Comment: Check with your provider regarding a static IP.

Comment: Yes, They tell me that it's not posible access to the static page by IP address (something like : 200.23.40.92/usernamehosting)